# Sharing ViewModel between three fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have three fragments A, B and C. B and C are child fragments of A. How do I get all three to share the same view model.
From [this](https://medium.com/@abhilashmyworld/communicate-between-fragments-using-viewmodel-e83344e9df53) medium article, this is what I should do:

```
viewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")       
}
```

However this one is about sharing a view model among two fragments and an activity so it can not work right in my case.

Comment: If B and C are children or A, then you can define a SharedViewModel scoped to the lifecycle of A and it could be shared with B and C.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? Inject your view model into your main root fragment `A`:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

and now you should be able to access this view model from `B` and `C` like this:

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels(
        ownerProducer = { this.requireParentFragment() }
    )
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! I don't know how it works but it works. Thanks alot

Comment: Hello, there is an error I get  if I try to access the viewModel from the childFragment when the parentFragment is not observing the viewModel. 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lokech.taxi.newjourney.NewJourneyViewModel'. How can I deal with it.

Comment: All is good. I fixed it with someone's help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041088/10030693