# Accessing ViewModel in ParentFragment from ChildFragment using viewModels

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I am trying to access the `ParentViewModel` for `ParentFragment` from `ChildFragment` using `viewModels`. This is my code.

```
// In ParentFragment

class ParentFragment : Fragment() {
    val parentViewModel: ParentViewModel by viewModels {
        ParentViewModelFactory(getRepository())
    }
    ...
}

// In ChildFragment

class ChildFragment : Fragment() {
    val parentViewModel: ParentViewModel by viewModels(
        { requireParentFragment() }
    )
    ...
}
```

However, this code only works when I setup a `LiveData` variable in `ParentViewModel` and have `ParentFragment` observe it like so:

```
parentViewModel.text.observe(this) {
    toast(it)
}
```

I have no use for observing the `ViewModel` from inside `ParentFragment`. I only need it to define the `lifecycle` for the `ChildFragments`.

If I get rid of the observation above I get this error:

> 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ParentViewModel'

How can I have the ChildFragments access the `ParentViewModel` without setting up dummy live data objects so as the `ParentFragment` can observe them.

Comment: Is the constructor of the viewmodel private? Can you post the minimal code for the viewmodel? ANd also the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ChildFragment you should pass factory when init it. Try this

```
class ChildFragment : Fragment() {
    val parentViewModel: ParentViewModel by viewModels(
        { requireParentFragment() }
    ) { ParentViewModelFactory(getRepository()) }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow. It works. Could you kindly explain why adding a factory solves the problem?

Comment: When you declare only in child fragment if you not pass factory it means android dont know how to init your view model. If you declare it in parent fragment it mean your view model already init in parent scope. And child fragment it only get current instance of parent view model without init it